# php function create permalink like wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8gBv.jpg)

hi i want php function to create permalink like wordpress that support unicode character also. Currently i am using below function working good but not support unicode character.

```
function create_slug_html($string, $ext='.html'){     
   $replace = '-';         
   $string=strtolower($string);     
   $string=trim($string);
   //remove query string     
   if(preg_match("#^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-_.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}#i",$string)){         
         $parsed_url = parse_url($string);         
         $string = $parsed_url['host'].' '.$parsed_url['path'];         
         //if want to add scheme eg. http, https than uncomment next line         
         //$string = $parsed_url['scheme'].' '.$string;     
   }      
   //replace / and . with white space     
   $string = preg_replace("/[\/\.]/", " ", $string);     
   $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);     
   //remove multiple dashes or whitespaces     
   $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);     
   //convert whitespaces and underscore to $replace     
   $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $replace, $string);     
   //limit the slug size     
   $string = substr($string, 0, 100);     
   //slug is generated     
   return ($ext) ? $string.$ext : $string;
```

}

suggest me any change or new code

Answer (score 1):

You may use [functions prefixed with mb](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) to provide multibyte support, for instance use *mb_ereg_replace* instead of *preg_replace*. Others include *mb_substr* and *mb_strtolower*.

However you have to specify the encoding since the default encoding is UTF-8 rather than unicode. This is done using [mb_regex_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-encoding.php).